# elastic search no living connection when sniffing on startup

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I use elastic search api for node.js.

my code is :

```
var elasticclient=new Elasticsearch.Client(
{
sniffOnStart:true,
sniffOnConnectionFault:true,
sniffInterval:540000,
hosts:['\* my elastic servers*\']
}
);
```

whenever I delete sniffOnStart it works.
But when sniffOnStart remains it throws the following error after trying to do a bulk:

```
Elasticsearch warnning: date
No living connection

{Error:No Living connections

at ... (script paths..)
message:'no living connections',
body:undefined,
status:undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

plz check your es servers config.When sniffOnStart is true,your node client will fetch the nodes info from http://yourip:youport/_cluster/nodes.If you deploy es with docker ,the node ip will be 172.xxx,which get from docker network. As your sniffInterval has been set to 540000,you may get No living connection after 540s .